# Choosing the right epsilon...

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

[image]

In this picture, a proof of the sum rule of limits is shown. Can someone explain to me why $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ is chosen? I don't understand why they chose $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$, when it could've been any other number as the denominator?...

Answer (score 2):

Answer is not unique as long as it solves the problem.

$\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is a good choice as it is symmetrical and it solves the problem since $\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

In fact, choosing any $\frac{\epsilon}{k}$ where $k \geq 2$ works.

However, we cannot choose for example $\frac{\epsilon}{3/2}$ as the sum would be $\frac{4\epsilon}{3} > \epsilon$.

You can also do fancy stuff such as choosing $\delta_1$ to get $f(x)$ within $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ of $L$ and choosing $\delta_2$ to get $g(x)$ within $\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$ of $M$ and your proof will still work but simplicy is good.

Comment: Regarding your statement of choosing any k,  k$\geq$2, if I chose 4, then e/4 +e/4 = e/2, which isn't epsilon. Wouldn't that be incorrect?

Comment: $$(L+M)-\epsilon < (L+M)-\frac{\epsilon}2 < f(x)+g(x) < (L+M) + \frac{\epsilon}2 < (L+M) + \epsilon$$ it still works but for choose something that is simple and try not to make readers doubt "hmmm... why did he purposely choose a smaller $\epsilon$ than necessary, did I miss anything. "

Comment: Ah. Ok. I don't understand the textbook when it says "we must get f(x) + g(x) as close to L+M by choosing delta so that f(x) and g(x) are each half the distance of L and M". I've tried graphing the statement, but i'm really confused on the f(x) + g(x) close to L+M part

Comment: That is the idea of limit, to find a region of $x$ such that the function value is close to the limit. I wouldn't say it is a **must** to choose them such that the distance is each half, it is a choice, a wise and elegant choice.

Comment: May I ask, what does this mean? δ = min(δ 1, δ 2)

Comment: If $\delta_1 = 0.1, \delta_2=0.3$, then $\delta= (0.1, 0.3)=0.1$, the minimum function chooses the smallest value.

Comment: So then why do we have to use the min function if we can just say delta = 0.1?

Comment: you do not know the value of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ exactly isn't it. how do you know which one is smaller in advance?

Comment: Well, if we're using the min function after identifying the values of delta 1 and 2, would it not be obvious wihch one is smaller?

Comment: that is why you can write the minimum function, it will be well defined.